# Automapper, mapping objects by linked association?

Tags: c#, automapper

Lets say I have these models

```
   public class Mouse
    {
        public string Cheese { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cat
    {
        public string Hairball { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dog
    {
        public string ChewyToy { get; set; }
    }
```

And I map a Mouse to a Cat then a Cat to a Dog:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Mouse, Cat>().ForMember(m => m.Hairball, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Cheese));
    Mapper.CreateMap<Cat, Dog>().ForMember(m => m.ChewyToy, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Hairball));
```

By extension, a Mouse should also be mapped to a Dog, right?
When I try to map between the two:

```
    var mouse = new Mouse() { Cheese = "Eat me" };

    Dog dog = Mapper.Map<Mouse, Dog>(mouse);
```

I get an exception:

> Trying to map App_Start.MapConfig+Mouse to
>   App_Start.MapConfig+Dog. Exception of type
>   'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.

How do I do this with out explicitly creating a map between a Mouse to a Dog? This is a simple example of a bigger issue. I'm also open to switching frameworks such as Value Injector, Glue, etc if they support this behavior.

Comment: write your own Automapper? this type of problem is a lot harder than you think. Think of creating a graph data structure to keep track of "transitive" mapping.

Comment: Sorry, but I saw `string Cheese` and thought "yummy!" Ignore this.

Comment: You can't, No solution other than Mapper.CreateMap<Mouse, Dog>(...)

Comment: Not only that, I think what you're looking for is not a mapper, but something more akin to messaging/pipes & filters model. It's actually difficult to take a bunch of nodes with inputs and outputs, create nodes, and automatically determine the right graph to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I do this with out explicitly creating a map between a Mouse to
>   a Dog?

The answer is simple: *you can't*.

Automapper has pretty straightforward logic for mapping objects. When you are adding new mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Mouse, Cat>();
```

New `TypeMap` is created and added to list of type maps. Yes, there is simple list. And each `TypeMap` has two properties: `DestinationType` and `SourceType`. Nothing in the middle. When you are trying to map some object, then list is simply searched for first `TypeMap` which has **exactly same** source and destination types, as specified in your mapping. It is done with following method ([ConfigurationStore](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/ConfigurationStore.cs) class is responsible for holding configured mappings):

```
TypeMap FindExplicitlyDefinedTypeMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
{
    return this._typeMaps.FirstOrDefault<TypeMap>(x => 
               ((x.DestinationType == destinationType) && 
                (x.SourceType == sourceType)));
}
```

So, for your sample there will be two `TypeMap` objects in list, and of course none of them matches condition of `DestinationType` equalt to `Dog` and `SourceType` equal to `Mouse`.

Comment: Do you know if its possible with other mapping frameworks such as Value Injector or Glue?

Comment: @Levitikon sorry, haven't used them (you can ask another question on those mappers). But I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @Levitikon Consider following. You have mappings for `A->C`, `A->B`, `C->D` and `B->D`. Pretty legal, yes? But what should happen when you are mapping `A` to `D`? Should we go `A->B->D` path, or `A->C->D`?

Also mapping framework supposed to be extremely fast, because most often they are used to map DTO objects to entities (or to view models) back and forth. So, performance matters.