# automapper ConvertUsing with multiple ITypeConverter implementations

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a typeconverter class that implements ITypeConverter for both an object and for a pager (inheriting IEnumerable) of the objects. 
e.g.

```
   class MyConverter : ITypeConverter<IFoo, FooModel>,
                       ITypeConverter<IPager<IFoo>, IPager<FooModel>>
    {
        public FooModel Convert(IFoo source, FooModel destination, ...) {...}
        public IPager<FooModel> Convert(IPager<IFoo> source, IPager<FooModel> destination, ...) {...}

    }
```

When given a pager, it uses the single object converter implementation anyway.

I know that Automapper will map collections automatically but shouldn't it prefer an explicit collection mapping if one exists? I could probably move the implementations into separate classes but is there another way to get it to use the pager implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You should have called CreateMap and ConvertUsing - did you do this?

```
cfg.CreateMap<IFoo, FooModel>().ConvertUsing<MyConverter>();
cfg.CreateMap<IPager<IFoo>, IPager<FooModel>>().ConvertUsing<MyConverter>();
```

?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I have other cases working. After simplifying I realized that I was trying to map transitively as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617250/automapper-mapping-objects-by-linked-association.